# How can I find out whether a crate is compatible with a specific Rust version?

Tags: rust, rust-crates

If I find a crate I'd like to use, how can I find out with which versions of Rust the crate works as expected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now, you either read the crate's documentation or test it yourself. Many larger crates test against an older pinned version of Rust in CI when they make a stability claim.

There is a [proposed RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1709) that would add the Rust version to the Cargo.toml file.