# why does `rust-version` (declared MSRV) not have to match _actual_ MSRV?

Tags: rust

A rust project can declare `rust-version = "A.B"`, say `1.58.0`. Due to dependencies, it may require `rustc` version `"A.C"`, say `1.60.0`, to successfully build. Rust tools do not reject this configuration.

This makes it difficult to find the latest versions of dependencies that are not past the declared `rust-version` ("declared MSRV") also listed at website `lib.rs`. I must manually set the dependency version, starting from the latest and then going backwards, until I find a version that will build. This is very tedious.

***Why is rust designed like this?***

It seems that rust should enforce declaring a `rust-version` that will compile with that actual version `rustc` (or current default toolset version). Then users would not be relegated to trying to build every version of a crate to find the actual MSRV for that crate (and the crate that will build with their project).  And the "published MSRV", like seen at website `lib.rs`, would be helpful instead of unhelpful.

## problem reproduction

For example, I know I need to use crate `Criterion` but I also want to support rust that's about two years old (late 2021 or early 2022). [I review `criterion` version MSRV](https://lib.rs/crates/criterion/versions). According to the website `lib.rs` entry, I can use `criterion = "0.3.6"` with MSRV `1.58`.

So I start a new project with `rust-version = "1.58.1"` (April 2022 release) using that toolset.

```text
$ rustup default 1.58.1
$ cargo init myproject
$ cd myproject
$ cargo build
```

file `Cargo.toml` should look like

```toml
[package]
name = "try2"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"
rust-version = "1.58.1"
```

Then I build my project

```text
$ cargo build
```

The build succeeds.

Now I add crate `criterion` as a dependency

```toml
[package]
edition = "2021"
name = "try2"
rust-version = "1.58.1"
version = "0.1.0"
[dependencies]
criterion = "0.3.6"
```

But now the build fails

```text
cargo build
    Updating crates.io index
  Downloaded csv-core v0.1.11
  Downloaded criterion-plot v0.4.5
  Downloaded criterion v0.3.6
  Downloaded serde_cbor v0.11.2
  Downloaded csv v1.3.0
  Downloaded 5 crates (1.1 MB) in 1.58s
error: package `rayon v1.8.0` cannot be built because
it requires rustc 1.63 or newer, while the currently
active rustc version is 1.58.1
```

So the "stated MSRV" as posted at `lib.rs` does not help me understand the actual version of criterion my project at 1.58.1 can use.

#### `cargo-msrv`

If I run tool [`cargo-msrv`](https://lib.rs/crates/cargo-msrv) then that finds an entirely different MSRV *1.63.0* .

```text
# need to update to recent version to install `cargo-msrv`
$ rustup default 1.72.0
$ cargo install cargo-msrv --version=0.15.1
$ rustup default 1.58.1
$ cargo msrv
Fetching index
Determining the Minimum Supported Rust Version (MSRV) for toolchain x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Using check command cargo check
Check for toolchain '1.65.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu' succeeded

Check for toolchain '1.60.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu' failed with:
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ error: package `rayon-core v1.12.0` cannot be built because it │
│ requires rustc 1.63 or newer, while the currently active rustc │
│ version is 1.60.0                                              │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

Check for toolchain '1.62.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu' failed with:
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ error: package `rayon-core v1.12.0` cannot be built because it │
│ requires rustc 1.63 or newer, while the currently active rustc │
│ version is 1.62.1                                              │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Check for toolchain '1.63.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu' succeeded
   Finished The MSRV is: 1.63.0   ███████████████████████ 00:00:01
```

### Summary

It seems the "stated MSRV" (according to website `lib.rs`) is not very helpful for determining the best dependency version to pin. I'm relegated to trying all the versions of `criterion` until I find a `criterion` crate that builds within my project.

Why not force projects to declare a `rust-version` and have some mechanism to test the project builds with that version?  Then the "published MSRV" (taken from `rust-version`) would be accurate and I wouldn't have to try to build so many versions of a crate.

### Related Questions

Related but not the same questions.

- [*How can I find out whether a crate is compatible with a specific Rust version?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45254863/how-can-i-find-out-whether-a-crate-is-compatible-with-a-specific-rust-version?rq=3)
- [*list minimum rust version required for rust project*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74133413/list-minimum-rust-version-required-for-rust-project)

Comment: FYI shepmaster [would have to have already participated here for a notification to be sent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).

Answer (score 3):

As it stands, there is no way to enforce that `rust-version` is accurate for downstream users.

Consider crate A and its dependency, crate B, compile with Rust 1.60, so the authors of crate A record their crate's `rust-version` as 1.60. But then at some time later, crate B gets a new (compatible) version that requires Rust 1.70. Now crate A's `rust-version` doesn't reflect its true MSRV - through no fault of its own - for new users of crate A or those that run `cargo update`.

That could be resolved if updating a crate's MSRV is considered a *breaking change* and thus require a major version bump, but there is no consensus from the community on whether that should be followed (sources: [1](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/rust-version-requirement-change-as-semver-breaking-or-not/20980) [2](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/rtp3yg/is_rust_compiler_version_dependency_update_a/)). So until that becomes the norm, dependencies can easily increase the true MSRV of their dependents independent from `rust-version`.

It also doesn't quite appear that this was the goal of the `rust-version` field anyway. From the [RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2495) and [tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/65262), it seems intention was to serve as an early failure mechanism - so that users don't get confusing compiler errors that could better be summarized by "update your compiler". Thus the `rust-version` is a lower bound where it is known that lesser Rust versions will (likely) fail, rather than a guarantee that Rust versions at or above will succeed.